# Testing objects containing the Date field

Tags: java, spring, testing

I have a class with a method that Bill generates. I have a DateUtil component to create the date

```
public Bill generateBill(List<ProvidedItem> providedItems) {
    Bill bill = new Bill();

    Date date = dateUtil.now();

    bill.setStartDate(date);
    bill.setEndDate(dateUtil.plusDays(date, ConstantValues.DEFAULT_DURATION_BILL_DAYS));

    return billDao.saveOrUpdate(bill);
}
```

I have test for method generate Bill

```
@Test
public void generateBill_shouldCorrectlyGenerateBill() {
    Bill actualBill = billService.generateBill(actualProvidedItems);

    Date date = dateUtil.now();
    Bill expectedBill = BillMother.createTestInstanceWithAmount(sumProvidedItems, date, dateUtil.plusDays(date,
            ConstantValues.DEFAULT_DURATION_BILL_DAYS));

    Assert.assertThat(actualBill, is(expectedBill));
}
```

BillMother:

```
public static Bill createTestInstanceWithAmount(BigDecimal totalAmount, Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    Bill bill = new Bill();
    bill.setStartDate(startDate);
    bill.setEndDate(endDate);
    bill.setTotalAmount(totalAmount);
    return bill;
}
```

I have different objects because the date is called at another time.

I can't skip these dates in the Equals method because they are one of the most important parts of this object

How to make it work properly in this situation?

Comment: If you consider making your methods non static that would allow you easy mocking of the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing keeping you away from successfuly testing that method is the date fields, you could just use the actualBill's start and end dates for setting the test instance's start and end dates, this is, assuming that your Bill class has getters for those 2 fields.

Oh and another slight suggestion, i think what you want to compare is the objects content not the object themselves. Because, unless you specifically override equals() method from Bill's class, 2 Bill references will only be equal if they are referencing the same object.

One possible solution to this, is like i said, overriding the equals() method from the class Bill as such:

```
 @override public boolean equals(Object o){  
    return o.instanceof(Bill) &&  
    o.getStartDate().equals(startDate) &&  
    o.getEndDate().equals(endDate) &&  
    o.getTotalAmount()==totalAmount;  
    }
```

One last thing, i would consider using the Java.Time library as it provides a set of more recent, more useful and tipically more efficient than those "old" libraries. Instead of Date you could use LocalDate.

Answer (score 1):

Use Mockito:

```
@Mock DateUtil dateUtil

when(dateUtil.now()).thenReturn(NOW);
```

Comment: It works for all dates in the test method. But calling `dateUtil.Now()` inside the tested method no longer works. So it doesn't solve the problem anymore. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: `Bill actualBill = billService.generateBill(actualProvidedItems);` This code snippet inside will generate a different date

Answer (score 0):

You can mock dateUtil using mockito (as in the above answer)

`when(dateUtil.now()).thenReturn(new Date());`

or

you can mock the date instantiation using the powerMockito.

`whenNew(Date.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(new Date());`